# Get latest data for all people in a table and then filter based on some criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to return the row of the highest value for timestamp (an integer) for each person (that has multiple entries) in a table. Additionally, I am only interested in rows with the field containing ABCD, but this should be done after filtering to return the latest (max timestamp) entry for each person.

```
SELECT table."person", max(table."timestamp")
FROM table
WHERE table."type" = 1
HAVING table."field" LIKE '%ABCD%'
GROUP BY table."person"
```

For some reason, I am not receiving the data I expect. The returned table is nearly twice the size of expectation. Is there some step here that I am not getting correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can 1st return a table having max(timestamp) and then use it in sub query of another select statement, following is query

```
  SELECT table."person", timestamp FROM 
 (SELECT table."person",max(table."timestamp") as timestamp, type, field FROM table GROUP BY table."person") 
    where type = 1 and field LIKE '%ABCD%'
```

Comment: The group by in the sub-select is invalid

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please explain why and update the right query ?

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer: as I understand your end goal, just move the `HAVING` clause to the `WHERE` section:

```
SELECT
  table."person", MAX(table."timestamp")
FROM table
WHERE
    table."type" = 1
AND table."field" LIKE '%ABCD%'
GROUP BY table."person";
```

This should return no more than 1 row per `table."person"`, with their associated maximum timestamp.

As an aside, I surprised your query worked at all.  Your `HAVING` clause referenced a column not in your query.  From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html) (and my experience):

> The fundamental difference between WHERE and HAVING is this: WHERE selects input rows before groups and aggregates are computed (thus, it controls which rows go into the aggregate computation), whereas HAVING selects group rows after groups and aggregates are computed.